# Firebase Unity3D desktop app (Mac/PC) - does it work or not?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

Firebase, in the doc here

Document "A":

https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup

it claims that it DOES now work for desktop builds. (So, in unity you create a Mac app or Windows app.)

[image]

1. it does work perfectly "in the Editor" (on Mac or PC), which is great
2. it does NOT seem to work as a Mac or PC build - I cannot get it to work

And here for instance..

Document "B":

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/unity

.. it suggests it is *not* working (although it's a bit confusing).

Is it not working yet, or did we just screw up?

As I mention below, you can't use **Firebase for VR** until this is done, since VR builds are Windows builds.

Comment: Hi, long time no talk.... there are many features in Firebase and only some of them got  implemented for Desktop standalone. Which features /API are you using?

Comment: hi - only realtime database.  it works fine >in the editor< but seemingly not in a build to a Mac App.  same deal on Windows ... hi @Programmer !

Comment: there's also this:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/49516956/294884  which I can't fathom

Comment: Authentication, Realtime Database, Remote Config and Cloud Storage should work for desktop according to the link from your question. Your realtime database **should** work. It's still in a beta phase so I am not surprised it doesn't even work. This is the right time to file for a bug report on their Github page. What Firebase version are you using?

Comment: hey @Programmer - (1) it **does not** work unfortunately (using the latest beta) ... (2) it seems based on F.V.P.'s answer below, and thank goodness for the answer, it would seem that simply "Document A" is just wrong.  "Document B" is sadly correct.

Comment: note @Programmer .. I say *"it does not work unfortunately (using the latest beta)"*, well, i could not get it working (maybe someone else can?)  However, sadly, the bloke from Firebase below seems to be saying that indeed, it is, not yet working as a build  :O

Comment: As a curiosity if you try it - the whole project just goes haywire, you see only a blank screen.  Well that's what we found anyway in a few tests.

Comment: I think the Firebase guy below just verified that it's only for the Editor. Since it works in the Editor, you can actually make it work outside the Editor but I think they don't want you to but you can do it anyways. They likely placed the DLL's somewhere in a folder that Unity will not compile. I don't have this plugin but I suspect the Editor folder. Simply copy those DLL's or scripts from that folder into `Assets/Plugins/x64` and you should be fine.

Comment: Finally, they might have a code that checks if this is an Editor or not, you can also remove that line of code too.  If this check is done in a DLL, you can decompile the DLL with .NET Reflector, use Reflexil plugin to remove that check OpCode and compile it back. Everything I just wrote is only possible if this actually work on the desktop Editor but not in a desktop build. It can be done

Comment: holy crap - I will try that idea OK ......  **Simply copy those DLL's or scripts from that folder into Assets/Plugins/x64 and you should be fine.** ...... whoa!!

Comment: big P @Programmer - how are you - there's one for you!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49736771

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*firebaser here*

While most Unity SDKs for Firebase should now work in the Unity editor, build targets for desktop environments are not yet supported. So: you can develop games targeting iOS and Android on the desktop, but you can't target desktop games yet.

For the latest supported platforms and the status of desktop support, you can check the Firebase documentation page on [setting up Firebase for Unity](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup).

Comment: Oh The desktop feature is only there for the Editor? I don't think this is made clear in the doc. What's wrong with making firebase available on desktops outside the Editor?

Comment: _another firebaser here_ At the moment we support a [subset of features on desktop platforms](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup#desktop_workflow_implementations_beta_feature_) .  You can actually build for desktop but we do not officially support shipping desktop games that use Firebase, the functionality is only provided for your development workflow.

Comment: hi @stewartmiles - unfortunately I believe you are ***incorrect***, my man.  This is adding to the confusion!  I don't think there are ***any*** features that actually work - as of today - when you build to the desktop.  I fear that "Document A" above is simply outright wrong.  (Document B is correct.)  Unfortunately  :/

Comment: @frankvanPuffelen - thanks a million for that.  Is it a lot to ask, is there any sort of vague timeline on this?  Just for ordinary realtime database.  Observation, **all VR projects need this**, cause they are Windows builds.  We have clients foaming at the mouth for this.  :O