# Large scene scene in Unity, far bigger than one Terrain?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Imagine a large free-roam game in Unity,

[image]

The yellow size indicates about the largest you can make a typical Terrain in Unity.

Art dept. will completely build, **meter by meter, the entire scene.**

**Please note, this has absolutely no connection to repeating scenery (as in runners) or procedural scenery (as in say some race games).**

Really, what is the correct and good way to do this in Unity?

- use say 50 or so terrains, each perhaps 100m x 100m ?
- can you even have or use that many terrains?

or what?

---

For anyone googling here.

The correct solution is indeed

## Terrain stitching

- that's it.

In practice you must use one of the tools available to do this (eg, TerrainFormer) or, your team will write from scratch a terrain stitcher.

Yes, you just use "many terrains".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach to the exact problem posed,

is in fact to just:

## "use lots of Terrains".

It seems to be perfectly viable in Unity to have many (dozens) of Terrain units, basically "sitting next to each other".

In practice, you'll need **TerrainFormer**

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/terrain/terrain-former-20052

or one of the **similar tools**.

(Or, I suppose, from scratch write your own tool to stitch terrains, and allow you manipulate them all at once, join the edge-heights perfectly, etc etc.)

It's not realistically possible to just perfectly sit many Terrains together (by hand), matching all the edges, etc etc.  So you're going to need a "stitcher" package for putting many Terrain squares together.

So, this huge area ..

[image]

has about 12 Terrain.

So that's the answer, you can indeed have "many, many" Terrain in a Unity project, you do indeed essentially just "sit them next to each other".  In practice it's not achievable unless you use one of the editor tools such as TerrainFormer.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this would have been with procedural mesh generation with [`MeshFilter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MeshFilter.html) and [`Mesh`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html) API but you mentioned that this not at all random or generative so that one is eliminated.

> It's just simply a very long, thin, hand-made environment

The best way in this case would be a *Modular Level Design*. You need to create Modular Assets. With this you can have a long road in pieces which can be tileable. A good modeling artist should be able to create and texture modular assets with 3D modeling packages like Blender, Maya or 3ds Max.

All the programmer has to do is make each asset a prefab then use the [`Instantiate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) function to instantiate them to create any distance of environment. You can also create a static environment in the scene from the Editor. Almost anything can be made into a modular Asset especially buildings and roads.

After assembling them in Unity, you can do static batch on all the instantiated modular parts with Unity's [`StaticBatchingUtility.Combine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/StaticBatchingUtility.Combine.html) to improve performance of the game since they are not being moved.

Below is an example of a modular road asset that can be used to create almost any amount of road:

[image]

Comment: hi PR! ...  honestly, it's not a road, nor a procedural road. There is no connection to a road - there is no road  :)  I edited to try to explain it better in the question: it is simply a (say) 5km long scenery. All completely handmade by the art dept.  (Some parts might be "a river", sometimes "walk through fields", maybe "1km of urban area to traverase" and so on.......... it just goes on and on for 5km.)

Comment: I know. I carefully read your question. You said "track-or-course" but I used a road as an example in my answer. Modular asset is used for this kind of stuff you mentioned in your question especially when it is long. The-same thing can be applied to track or environmental places. By using modular assets, you will maintain the **quality** of the track, shorten the model size, the huge texture size(albedo, normal etc) by re-using some of the modules. You can even add different decals to each module by either using different texture or material.

Comment: You can also do this from script to improve performance. You can assembly the whole track in the 3D package and import it into Unity or even assemble them in unity. It doesn't matter what the shape of the track looks like. The artist should be able to create different variation of the modules like jaggedy, sometimes long up and down hill or curved ones. Like I said in my answer, it requires a good artist to do this but it can be done.Many games use this incldung Skyrim and fallout4 and they do mostly for the sake of quality as you mentioned in your question.

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QBAM27YbKZg) GDC videos shows how Bethesda Studios used Modular asset to handle their design.  If you artists are struggling with this, link them to [this](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/asset-workflows-modular-level-design-857) course/lesson. It should get them started and that can be applied to tracks too. *If you have any other question, don't hesitate to ask*. If you think I am still confused with your question or read it wrong, please add a screenshot of what your track looks like and I will tell you if this still applies or not.

Comment: @Fattie Yes, multiple Terrain objects are permitted.

Comment: Oh well, your edit just removed the track/course and quality keyword from it and the image you uploaded is not helpful to me :(. I was expecting  a real life image. I thought you were doing something like [this](http://drawenterprises.com/wp-content/gallery/track-and-field/p1010114-w400.jpg) when you said track/course. I can't tell what you are doing now. Sorry for the confusion. Although, if the image I linked in this comment is similar to what you are doing then this answer is still what you are looking for.

Comment: The answer is still hugely useful to many people, and you've perfectly explained the standard technique for dynamic tracks.  It's in the nature of game architecture that solutions are hard to pin down!  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You already answered your question

> in this case would it be better to not bother with Unity's otherwise excellent Terrain, and the modellers would just outright build the long course/scenery? (Obviously you'd have to chunk it so it all occludes fine)

I think it's the way to go. If the performance is an issue, try putting each chunk in different scenes and then have a master scene to load them [async](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync.html) and [additively](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.LoadSceneMode.html). And of course you want to unload each scene as it becomes invisible in the camera.

I personally go with your own solution which is letting the Unity Occlusion Culling system to take care of the hiding and showing chunks. I only go with the separate scenes approach if I'm not getting enough performance this way.

Comment: So you'd go with chunks - actually not using Terrain.  interesting!

Answer (score -1):

I recently had the same problem. We build a tilebased infinite runner with road crossings. The camera was positioned behind and over the car looking down on the street and the player car. So the setup is quite comparable.

We used Curvy from the Asset store to create paths for moving the player and also for creating the geometry of the streets and the surroundings among the streets.

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/level-design/curvy-splines-7038

It is also easy to spawn tiles with curvy paths and combine them at runtime. So you can separate long distances into smaller segments and spawn them randomly.

We also used QuickBrush from ProCore to quickly paint environment detail to the geometry like trees, bushes or stones. I think procore tools are now implemented in the new Unity 2018 version.

Worked quite well.

Comment: Hey Bernhard.  As I mention, it's not an infinite runner - no track generation.  Just a long, thin hand-built environment!  Yes, I've often used Curvy or similar for infinite runners (I used to like SSP best, but it is not supported any more!)  Cheers!